# Find the terminal velocity of skydiver using differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

I am studying differential equations in university and I came across this problem:

> A parachutist whose mass is $75$ kg drops from a helicopter hovering
>   $4000\hbox{m}$ above the ground and falls towards the earth under the
>   influence of gravity. Assume that the gravitational force remains
>   constant during the flight, and that the drag due to air resistance is
>   proportional to the velocity of the parachutist, with a
>   proportionality constant $b = 150$ $N\hbox{s}/\hbox{m}$ when the chute is open. The
>   chute opens immediately after the parachutist leaves the helicopter

The equation of motion (Newton’s 2nd law) they provide this:

$m \frac{dV}{dt} = mg − b\times V$

$m = 75$
$b = 150$
$g = 9.81$

**The question:** Obtain an expression for the velocity of the parachutist as a function of time. What is her/his terminal velocity? ($g = 9.81 \hbox{m}/\hbox{s}^2$)

I used the method of integrating factor to express the velocity as a function of time

$V = -4.905 + C e^{-2t}$ I think this answer the first part

I am having problem with the terminal velocity. I know it cannot be higher than $9.81,$ but I don't know what I should do to find this. My guess is either $4.905 \hbox{m}/\hbox{s}^2$ or $9.81$.

Comment: Hint: what is the value of $dV/dt$ at terminal velocity?

Comment: It should be 0.

Comment: So you have $0 = mg - bV$, what do you need to do from here?

Comment: Alright I took the equation and transformed it to bV = mg; therefore, v = mg/b. b=150; m=75 means that V = 1/2g = 4.905!

Comment: so 4.905 is the answer. right?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Alright thanks!

Comment: Don't forget the units for $b$ and $m$: the terminal *velocity* is $4.9m/s$ not $m/s^{2}$.